Angular Reactive Form - Issue when patching form control with object instead of value
I’m using mat-select in my Angular form to let users select multiple countries as objects with id and name properties. However, I need to patch the form control with the full country objects instead of just their IDs, but it doesn’t behave as expected. Here’s the relevant code snippet!!!
I need to patch the form control with full country objects instead of IDs, but currently, it's only working with country IDs.
<form [formGroup]="countryForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Countries</mat-label>
      <mat-select formControlName="countryControl" multiple >
          <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">
              {{ country.name }}
          </mat-option>
      </mat-select>

  </mat-form-field>

  </form>
  <div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" type="button" (click)="patchFormWithCountry()">Patch Form</button>
  </div>

Here is my ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Form field appearance variants */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-appearance-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-appearance-example.html',
})
export class FormFieldAppearanceExample {
  countryForm: FormGroup;
  countries: any[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'United States' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Canada' },
    { id: 3, name: 'United Kingdom' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Australia' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Germany' },
    { id: 6, name: 'France' },
    { id: 7, name: 'Italy' },
    { id: 8, name: 'Spain' },
    { id: 9, name: 'India' },
    { id: 10, name: 'China' },
    { id: 11, name: 'Japan' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Brazil' },
    { id: 13, name: 'South Africa' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Mexico' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Russia' },
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.countryForm = this.fb.group({
      countryControl: [''],
    });
  }

  patchFormWithCountry() {
    const selectedCountries = [
      { id: 1, name: 'United States' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Canada' },
      { id: 3, name: 'United Kingdom' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Australia' },
    ];

    this.countryForm.patchValue({
      countryControl: selectedCountries,
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('Form submitted:', this.countryForm.value);
  }
}


You need to implement the compareWith function so that the <mat-select> option can be mapped/patched when the value is a complex value such as an object.
Reference: Getting and setting the select value
<mat-select
  formControlName="countryControl"
  multiple
  [compareWith]="countryCompareWithFn"
>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">
    {{ country.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>

countryCompareWithFn = (country: any, value: any) => country.id == value.id;

Demo @ StackBlitz

You have to import CommonModule for ngFor to work.
Secondly you have to make sure you use the same memory reference, since objects and arrays are stored as references in memory. So I filter the original array for these countries, here I use the array method filter which filters out the values based on a condition. I use the array method includes to check if the value is present inside the array.
The country control form, should not be initialized to a string, it should just be an empty array.
this.countryForm = this.fb.group({
  countryControl: [],
});

Snippet:
patchFormWithCountry() {
  const toFilter = [
    'United States',
    'Canada',
    'United Kingdom',
    'Australia',
  ];
  const selectedCountries = this.countries.filter((item: any) => toFilter.includes(item.name))

  this.countryForm.patchValue({
    countryControl: selectedCountries,
  });
}

Stackblitz Demo
